# Create a modal dialog with qml and qtquick 1

Tags: qml, showmodaldialog

I am trying to create a customized UI messagebox with QML. I have finished the UI but I cannot make it a modal dialog (prevent the program from proceeding without interact with my messagebox). This is a very common thing with QMessageBox (via calling exec, information,..)

Could you tell me how to achieve that with Qt4 and QtQuick 1.1? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Look at this http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-messagedialog.html

Comment: Hi Jaques: I am using Qt4 not Qt5

Comment: A workaround to this may be to add a layer that will swallow the touch events and be a parent to your messagebox

Comment: Hi Nadarian: by doing that we can only prevent interactions from users but we can't halt the process to wait for user's choice from the message box

Comment: @PhamNguyenBinh I am no guru in case of qml, but I can't imagine a situation where actual layer overlap doesn't stop from going further with the program. I mean that if you show the messagebox and a layer that covers anything else, the user would have to meet the specified requirements (f.e chcek. one checkbox) otherwise he would not be allowed to proceed.

Comment: @Nadarian We can only prevent users' actions but not the program sequence actions. For example: 
bool result = myMessageBox::information(...); if (result == true) {//do sth here} .
Here we can't prevent the program from executing the condition IF before user chosing OK or Cancel button in the messageBox

Comment: Why you just can't place the statement in the `onYes` method in the messageBox? It's the messageBox which should call actions not just giving the result "Yes" "No" or "Canceled"